# I typed su <user> and my terminal didn't respond. Now I don't know how to exit, ctrl+D doesn't work

Tags: gnu-screen, su

I didn't check if `su` was blocked so I directly typed `su <user>`, and then nothing happened except that it "loaded"... however, it didn't give me access to a new line, instead I'm stuck without being able to type in a new line. I tried exit or Ctrl+D but it doesn't respond, now I don't know what to do. I was using ssh with screen, so whenever I close the terminal and ssh again I'm stuck with the same page where su  seems to be loading forever... any help on how to solve this?

Comment: `except that it "loaded"` what does that mean? `whenever I close the terminal and ssh again` should result in a new session ... so, apparently the machine you're connecting to is broken somehow - reboot it

Comment: I'm using screen, so the page where I was is preserved, I incorrectly used the term loading, I meant I typed the command, press enter and nothing happened but it also didn't give me a new line so I cannot type anything on the terminal. (well I can type stuff but it is the continuation of the same line which doesn't do anything after pressing enter)... now I kill the screen session but still when ssh again goes back to the same page.. is there a way to solve this without rebooting the whole system?

Comment: @christianortiz If you kill/exit the screen session, log out from the system, log back in, and start a new screen session and you are still stuck with no response from the cli, then you should reboot the system. One question however is, did you get a shell prompt after you logged back in but before you started a new screen session?

Comment: I didn't realise using screen worked like that. I thought if you make a new connection you have to also re-establish the connection to the *screen* process - I didn't realise ssh did that for you